# Nokogiri parse HTML table in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I need to parse a HTML table from a URL using Nokogiri. My HTML looks like this:

```
<table class="tbl" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" id="gvResult" style="width:100%;">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="trh">
         <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$b$b$gvResult','Sort$1')">Фирма</a></th>
         <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$b$b$gvResult','Sort$2')">Артикул</a></th>
         <th scope="col">Инф.</th>
         <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$b$b$gvResult','Sort$3')">Описание</a></th>
         <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$b$b$gvResult','Sort$6')">Нал.</a></th>
         <th scope="col" style="width:55px;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$b$b$gvResult','Sort$8')">Мин. заказ, шт</a></th>
         <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$b$b$gvResult','Sort$5')">Ожидаемый срок, дн. </a><a href="/help/hint/default.aspx?id=43" onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this, event,this.href,30,20);return false;"><img src="http://s.exist.ru/img/q2.gif" alt="&#1055;&#1086;&#1084;&#1086;&#1097;&#1100;" /></a></th>
         <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$b$b$gvResult','Sort$7')">Цена</a></th>
         <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="tabletitle" colspan="12">Запрошенный артикул</td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="colorize(this);" id="item_0" tcolor="">
         <td class="artMerge" id="item_0" rowspan="2"><a onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false;" href="hint/?s=47721138-000d-40c7-99f1-02d2f0005c83">Knecht (Mahle Filter)</a></td>
         <td class="artMerge" rowspan="2" style="white-space:nowrap;">O * * * D</td>
         <td class="artMerge" align="center" rowspan="2" style="white-space:nowrap;"></td>
         <td class="artMerge" rowspan="2" style="padding:10px 10px 0 10px;">Фильтр масляный</td>
         <td align="center">99</td>
         <td align="center">1</td>
         <td class="statis"><a class="stat" onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false" href="/stat/hint/deliv.aspx?d=0&amp;s=0100f98e-5c00-38be-0297-2f1100002de2" target="_blank">0</a></td>
         <td class="price" align="right">56&nbsp;400 р.</td>
         <td class="basket"><a title="&#1050;&#1091;&#1087;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100;" href="/profile/orders/basket.aspx?pid=83A07C7A&amp;in=0100f98e-5c00-38be-0297-2f1100002de2&amp;sr=-4"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="colorize(this);" id="item_1" tcolor="">
         <td align="center">1782</td>
         <td align="center">1</td>
         <td class="statis"><a class="stat" onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false" href="/stat/hint/deliv.aspx?d=1&amp;s=0100f98e-5c00-b5be-0297-0f1200002de2" target="_blank">1</a></td>
         <td class="price" align="right">55&nbsp;000 р.</td>
         <td class="basket"><a title="&#1050;&#1091;&#1087;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100;" href="/profile/orders/basket.aspx?pid=83A07C7A&amp;in=0100f98e-5c00-b5be-0297-0f1200002de2&amp;sr=-4"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="tabletitle" colspan="12">Аналоги (заменители) для запрошенного артикула <a href="/news/newstext.aspx?id=1367" target="_blank"><img src="http://s.exist.ru/img/q2.gif" alt="&#1055;&#1086;&#1084;&#1086;&#1097;&#1100;" /></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="colorize(this);" id="item_2" tcolor="">
         <td class="firmname" id="item_2"><a onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false;" href="hint/?s=e0c712d8-215d-4000-9a64-f02c7200005c">Alco</a></td>
         <td style="white-space:nowrap;">M * * * 5</td>
         <td align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;"></td>
         <td>Фильтр масляный</td>
         <td align="center">1</td>
         <td align="center">1</td>
         <td class="statis"><a class="stat" onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false" href="/stat/hint/deliv.aspx?d=0&amp;s=0100f98e-5c00-71fb-0241-720c00002c7d" target="_blank">0</a></td>
         <td class="price" align="right">37&nbsp;700 р.</td>
         <td class="basket"><a title="&#1050;&#1091;&#1087;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100;" href="/profile/orders/basket.aspx?pid=83A07C7A&amp;in=0100f98e-5c00-71fb-0241-720c00002c7d&amp;sr=-4"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="colorize(this);" id="item_3" tcolor="">
         <td class="firmname" id="item_3"><a onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false;" href="hint/?s=b113459e-001c-4000-a33e-5021bd20005c">Bosch</a></td>
         <td style="white-space:nowrap;">1 * * * 9</td>
         <td align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;"></td>
         <td>Фильтр масляный</td>
         <td align="center">8</td>
         <td align="center">1</td>
         <td class="statis"><a class="stat" onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false" href="/stat/hint/deliv.aspx?d=0&amp;s=0100f98e-5c00-3495-0002-bd11000021c2" target="_blank">0</a></td>
         <td class="price" align="right">30&nbsp;200 р.</td>
         <td class="basket"><a title="&#1050;&#1091;&#1087;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100;" href="/profile/orders/basket.aspx?pid=83A07C7A&amp;in=0100f98e-5c00-3495-0002-bd11000021c2&amp;sr=-4"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="colorize(this);" id="item_4" tcolor="">
         <td class="firmname" id="item_4"><a onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false;" href="hint/?s=40f20c71-000a-400f-bd7d-02c720005c78">Champion</a></td>
         <td style="white-space:nowrap;">X * * * 6</td>
         <td align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;"></td>
         <td>Фильтр масляный</td>
         <td align="center">1</td>
         <td align="center">1</td>
         <td class="statis"><a class="stat" onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false" href="/stat/hint/deliv.aspx?d=0&amp;s=0100f98e-5c00-713d-0142-720c00002cb0" target="_blank">0</a></td>
         <td class="price" align="right">59&nbsp;500 р.</td>
         <td class="basket"><a title="&#1050;&#1091;&#1087;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100;" href="/profile/orders/basket.aspx?pid=83A07C7A&amp;in=0100f98e-5c00-713d-0142-720c00002cb0&amp;sr=-4"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="colorize(this);" id="item_5" tcolor="">
         <td class="firmname" id="item_5"><a onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false;" href="hint/?s=50d11138-0008-4436-b40f-02d2f0005cc4">Clean filters</a></td>
         <td style="white-space:nowrap;">M * * * 0</td>
         <td align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;"></td>
         <td>Фильтр масляный</td>
         <td align="center">100</td>
         <td align="center">1</td>
         <td class="statis"><a class="stat" onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false" href="/stat/hint/deliv.aspx?d=0&amp;s=0100f98e-5c00-385f-012b-2f1100002df5" target="_blank">0</a></td>
         <td class="price" align="right">32&nbsp;500 р.</td>
         <td class="basket"><a title="&#1050;&#1091;&#1087;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100;" href="/profile/orders/basket.aspx?pid=83A07C7A&amp;in=0100f98e-5c00-385f-012b-2f1100002df5&amp;sr=-4"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="colorize(this);" id="item_6" tcolor="">
         <td class="firmname" id="item_6"><a onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false;" href="hint/?s=e0cb777d-0ecd-4000-8f30-802be890005c">Filtron</a></td>
         <td style="white-space:nowrap;">O * * * 1</td>
         <td align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;"></td>
         <td>Фильтр масляный</td>
         <td align="center">10</td>
         <td align="center">1</td>
         <td class="statis"><a class="stat" onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false" href="/stat/hint/deliv.aspx?d=0&amp;s=0100f98e-5c00-b781-0297-e80c00002be2" target="_blank">0</a></td>
         <td class="price" align="right">29&nbsp;000 р.</td>
         <td class="basket"><a title="&#1050;&#1091;&#1087;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100;" href="/profile/orders/basket.aspx?pid=83A07C7A&amp;in=0100f98e-5c00-b781-0297-e80c00002be2&amp;sr=-4"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="colorize(this);" id="item_7" tcolor="">
         <td class="firmname" id="item_7"><a onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false;" href="hint/?s=64e20c71-000c-40c6-8e51-02c720005c0f">Fram</a></td>
         <td style="white-space:nowrap;">C * * * O</td>
         <td align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;"></td>
         <td>Фильтр масляный</td>
         <td align="center">31</td>
         <td align="center">1</td>
         <td class="statis"><a class="stat" onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false" href="/stat/hint/deliv.aspx?d=0&amp;s=0100f98e-5c00-7151-00e8-720c00002c21" target="_blank">0</a></td>
         <td class="price" align="right">45&nbsp;500 р.</td>
         <td class="basket"><a title="&#1050;&#1091;&#1087;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100;" href="/profile/orders/basket.aspx?pid=83A07C7A&amp;in=0100f98e-5c00-7151-00e8-720c00002c21&amp;sr=-4"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="colorize(this);" id="item_8" tcolor="">
         <td class="firmname" id="item_8"><a onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false;" href="hint/?s=a1135e09-11ba-4000-a216-d02b3670005c">Hengst</a></td>
         <td style="white-space:nowrap;">E * * * 8</td>
         <td align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;"></td>
         <td>Фильтр масляный</td>
         <td align="center">10</td>
         <td align="center">1</td>
         <td class="statis"><a class="stat" onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false" href="/stat/hint/deliv.aspx?d=0&amp;s=0100f98e-5c00-35e4-0024-361100002b92" target="_blank">0</a></td>
         <td class="price" align="right">48&nbsp;900 р.</td>
         <td class="basket"><a title="&#1050;&#1091;&#1087;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100;" href="/profile/orders/basket.aspx?pid=83A07C7A&amp;in=0100f98e-5c00-35e4-0024-361100002b92&amp;sr=-4"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="colorize(this);" id="item_9" tcolor="">
         <td class="firmname" id="item_9"><a onclick="javascript:ShowTipLayer(this,event,this.href, 30,130); return false;" 
        ...
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Also note that it has Russian symbols.

My Ruby code looks like this:

```
html = open('http://exist.by/price.aspx?pcode=ox143d')
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'pp'
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
    doc.encoding = 'utf-8'

    rows = doc.xpath('//table[@id="gvResultTable"]/tbody/tr[@id="item_1"]')
    @details = rows.collect do |row|
      detail = {}
      [
        [:firmname, 'td[1]/text()'],
        [:price, 'td[8]/text()'],
      ].each do |name, xpath|
        detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
      end
      detail
    end
    pp @details
    logger.warn("!!!!!!!!!!")
    logger.warn(@details)
```

I don't know how to correctly fetch data in `tr` with `itemid`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you're having trouble, and what your question is?

Comment: @MarkThomas  i need to fetch data from table (you can see url from code) and get from there values of brand and it's price to my app. A part of table cod is above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The HTML is flawed; There are more than one element with the same `id` attribute: `<tr onclick="colorize(this);" id="item_2" tcolor="">   <td class="firmname" id="item_2">`.
2. The `id` of the `table` element in the HTML is "`gvResult`" while in the Ruby code you are asking Nokogiri to look for a table where "`id=gvResultTable`".
3. Nokogiri uses UTF-8 encoding to store strings internally, so you shouldn't have any problem with Russian characters.

Provided the HTML can be fixed, this works fine:

HTML:

```
<table id="gvResult">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="item_1">
        <td class="firmname">Example1</td>
        <td class="price">42.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="item_2">
       <td class="firmname">Example2</td>
       <td class="price">24.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ruby:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

html = open('http://www.example.com/page')

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.encoding = 'utf-8'

rows = doc.search('//tr[starts-with(@id, "item_")]')
  @details = rows.collect do |row|
      detail = {}
      [
        [:firmname, 'td[1]/text()'],
        [:price, 'td[2]/text()'],
      ].each do |name, xpath|
        detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
      end
      detail
  end
pp @details
```

I presumed that you want to get the data from all the `tr` elements with an `id` like "`item_\d+`" hence I used `doc.search('//tr[starts-with(@id, "item_")]')`. Change it to suit your needs.

Comment: i could'nt change html... this is not my page

Comment: I did mention "Provided the HTML can be fixed....."  :-)
The code will still work, give it a try.